# How to compare a file to a list in linux with one line code?

Tags: bash

Hey so got another predicament that I am stuck in. I wanted to see approximately how many Indian people are using the stampede computer. So I set up an indian txt file in vim that has about 50 of the most common surnames in india and I want to compare those names in the file to the user name list.

So far this is the code I have

getent passwd | cut -f 5 -d: | cut -f -d' '

getent passwd gets the userid list which is going to look like this
tg827313:x:827313:8144474:Brandon Williams

the cut functions will get just the last name so the output of the example will be

Williams

Now can use the grep function to compare files but how do I use it to compare the getent passwd list with the file?

Answer (score 1):

To count how many of the last names of computer users appear in the file `namefile`, use:

```
getent passwd | cut -f 5 -d: | cut -f -d' ' | grep -wFf namefile | wc -l
```

#### How it works

- `getent passwd | cut -f 5 -d: | cut -f -d' '`

  This is your code which I will assume works as intended for you.
- `grep -wFf namefile`

  This selects names that match a line in `namefile`. The `-F` option tells `grep` not to use regular expressions for the names.  The names are assumed to be fixed strings.  The option `-f` tells `grep` to read the strings from file.  `-w` tells `grep` to match whole words only.
- `wc -l`

  This returns a count of the lines in the output.

Comment: the grep -Ff function, what does the second f do? I had the grep -F function but it was just returning 0 and I didn't understand why?

Comment: @SulimanSharif `-F` tells `grep` to use fixed strings, as opposed to regexes.  `-f file` tells `grep` to get those strings from `file`.

Comment: Okay so I am understanding the -f and the -w and why those are implemented but now I guess I am questioning why we wouldn't want to use  regular expressions I mean obviously I am seeing a difference that in the output a space between the lines is being eliminated is that considered the regular expression?

Comment: @SulimanSharif Spaces don't require regular expressions but can you clarify?  In particular, what is "a space between the lines"?  Is it an empty line?  I was under the impression that you were matching last names.  How do spaces enter into this?

Comment: When I use the code getent passwd | cut -f 5 - d: | cut -f 2 -d' ' | grep -wf namefile  it outputs like this Shah-empty line - Singh- empty line - Khan and with the  getent passwd | cut -f 5 - d: | cut -f 2 -d' ' | grep -wFf namefile Shah, Singh, Khan with no empty lines in between

Comment: I think I am confused on the term regular expression because it just seems like a string

Comment: @SulimanSharif I cannot reproduce your blank line behavior.  Can you show me some minimal subset of the output from `getent passwd | cut -f 5 - d: | cut -f 2 -d' '` and a short version of `namefile` that demonstrates the blank line behavior on that output?

Comment: @SulimanSharif In brief, a regular expression has wildcards.  `Tom.*` means `Tom` followed by any number of any characters.  Thus, `Tom.*` would match `Tom` and `Tomas` and `Tommy`.  A fixed string has no such wildcards.